# Background login with OAuth

Tags: cookies, twitter, client, oauth

I'm soon to write a web based Twitter client which I plan to allow users to login with OAuth. My question is; can, once a user has logged in once already, my app login later and 'background' process their feed for them? I.E. does the user have to 'be there'?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when they have autorized the login you can keep them loggedin. Just like applications like tweetdeck do. Check out http://hueniverse.com/2007/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-i-overview/ for a walkthrough.